# Pagination click on page index load only the first page always

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, jakarta-ee, pagination

I am trying to paginate rows of a table inside my servlet using hibernate.But once I click on the desire index of the page it always gives me only the first set of row of the table.

My servlet code:

```
    int pageIndex = 0;
    int totalNumberOfRecords = 0;
    int numberOfRecordsPerPage = 5;

    String sPageIndex = request.getParameter("pageIndex");

    if (sPageIndex == null) {
        pageIndex = 1;
    } else {
        pageIndex = Integer.parseInt(sPageIndex);
    }
    int s = (pageIndex * numberOfRecordsPerPage) - numberOfRecordsPerPage;


List<ProductHasSize> phs = ses.createCriteria(ProductHasSize.class)
                    .setFirstResult(s)
                    .setMaxResults(numberOfRecordsPerPage)
                    .list();

            for (ProductHasSize pro : phs) {... some html content here...}
            List<ProductHasSize> phs1 = ses.createCriteria(ProductHasSize.class)
                .setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).list();
        Iterator i = phs1.iterator();
        if (i.hasNext()) {
            Object o = i.next();
            totalNumberOfRecords = Integer.parseInt(o.toString());
        }

        int noOfPages = totalNumberOfRecords / numberOfRecordsPerPage;
        if (totalNumberOfRecords > (noOfPages * numberOfRecordsPerPage)) {
            noOfPages = noOfPages + 1;
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= noOfPages; j++) {
            String myurl = "products.jsp?pageIndex=" + j;
            String active = j == pageIndex ? "active" : "";
            pagination = pagination + "<li class='" + active + "'><a href=" + myurl + ">" + j + "</a></li>";

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To debug this code, you have to put logs at every stage and ensure you get desired result at each stage. Because the bug can be anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace:

```
 if (i.hasNext()) {
```

With:

```
 while(i.hasNext()) {
```

And write the while loop like this:

```
  while(i.hasNext()) {
        Object o = i.next();
        totalNumberOfRecords += Integer.parseInt(o.toString());

 int noOfPages = totalNumberOfRecords / numberOfRecordsPerPage;
    if (totalNumberOfRecords > (noOfPages * numberOfRecordsPerPage)) {
        noOfPages = noOfPages + 1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Last `}` is for what ?? And changing `if` to `while` did not solve the problem.

Comment: } is the end of while

Comment: Then what about
 `totalNumberOfRecords = Integer.parseInt(o.toString());
    }`

Comment: I updated the code 
`int noOfPages = 0 ;
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                Object o = i.next();
                totalNumberOfRecords = Integer.parseInt(o.toString());

                noOfPages = totalNumberOfRecords / numberOfRecordsPerPage;
                if (totalNumberOfRecords > (noOfPages * numberOfRecordsPerPage)) {
                    noOfPages = noOfPages + 1;
                }
            }`  because `noOfPages` variable not visible to the for loop but sorry still get the same problem.

Comment: @johndoe try to add  +  like above in :totalNumberOfRecords += Integer.parseInt(o.toString());

Comment: @johndoe what size of your list phs1 ?

Comment: it's for that you cant have other result , the size should grether than 1

Comment: But I have 10 records in my DB. When I change `int numberOfRecordsPerPage = 5;` to `int numberOfRecordsPerPage = 10;` it shows al the records with single page index.

Comment: `noOfPages = totalNumberOfRecords(10) / numberOfRecordsPerPage(5); `
gives me 2 for `noOfPages`

Comment: I think it should be 10 is divided by numberOfRecordsPerPage.